# Генерация случайного числа, с неравномерным распределнием

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Как можно получить случайное число в диапазоне `[0, 100]`, так чтобы значения в основном получались рядом с центром диапазона?

То есть значения из диапазона `[40, 60]` должны получаться чаще чем остальные.

Равномерно распределённое число в этом диапазоне получаю так:

```
Math.random() * 100
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30492259/5812238

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Наиболее простой способ — сгенерировать два числа в диапазоне `[0, 50]` и сложить их

Это даст распределение чисел с максимальной вероятностью получить число в центре, и постепенным уменьшением вероятности от центра к краям.

Увеличивая число случайных чисел и уменьшая диапазон их генерации (соответственно с двух случайных чисел и диапазона `[0, 50]` до `n` случайных чисел и диапазона `[0, 100/n]`) можно ещё больше увеличить вероятность получения чисел рядом с центром по сравнению с числами возле края:

```js
// случайное число в диапазоне [0, maximum]
// чем больше numberRandoms, тем с большей вероятностью получаются числа ближе к центру (числу maximum/2)
function weightedRandom(maximum, numberRandoms) {
    let result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberRandoms; ++i)
        result += Math.random() * (maximum / numberRandoms);
    return result;
}

console.log(weightedRandom(100, 2));
```

График распределения получившихся чисел для разных `n`:

[image: сглаженная гистограмма распределения чисел для различных <code>n</code>]

## Общий случай

- Имеется генератор *равномерно* распределённых случайных чисел на отрезке `[0, 1]`
- Хочется получить генератор случайных чисел из некоторого [распределения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9)

Предполагаем, что распределение задано с помощью [*функции распределения*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Тогда можно воспользоваться [*функцией квантилей*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C), которая является *обратной* к функции распределения. А именно надо сгенерировать случайное число на отрезке `[0, 1]` и применить к нему функцию квантилей, получится случайное число, соответствующее имеющейся функции распределения.

Хотя код получается очень простым, генерация некоторых распространённых распределений (например, [нормального](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) таким способом не является простой, из-за сложности нахождения функции квантилей.